# Unable to run Visual Studio Code with GUI when using a Singularity container: Get gtk, dbus and dconf errors

Tags: ubuntu, x11, docker, container

I am trying to avoid installing lots of dependencies of another software (Blender) on my laptop running an Ubuntu 16.04. Therefore, I decided to I build a Singularity container that has those dependencies so that I can compile Blender through that container. So my goal is to also have VS Code in the container, run it visually, compile Blender on my machine locally and do debugging/code editing etc. Here's how I build my container with VS Code installed in it:

```
BootStrap: docker
From: nvidia/cuda:9.0-devel-ubuntu16.04

%post

apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install locales
locale-gen en_US.UTF-8
apt-get -y update && apt-get -y install make \
                                        dpkg \
                                        wget \
                                        bzip2 \
                                        libglib2.0-0 \
                                        libxext6 \
                                        libsm6 \
                                        libxrender1 \
                                        g++ \
                                        gcc \
                                        xvfb \
                                        libyaml-cpp-dev \
                                        git \
                                        cmake \
                                        vim \
                                        curl \
                                        ca-certificates \
                                        software-properties-common \
                                        python3 \
                                        python3-pip \
                                        gdb \
                                        libopenexr-dev \
                                        zlib1g-dev \
                                        xserver-xorg \
                                        freeglut3-dev \
                                        mesa-utils \
                                        libreadline-dev \
                                        gnuplot \
                                        gnuplot-qt \
                                        unzip \
                                        libboost-all-dev \
                                        libnss3 \
                                        libgconf-2-4 \
                                        libasound2 \
                                        libsecret-1-0 \
                                        libnss3 \
                                        libgconf-2-4 \
                                        libasound2 \
                                        libatk-adaptor \
                                        libgail-common \
                                        libcanberra-gtk-module \
                                        gtk2-engines \
                                        gtk2-engines-*

apt-get -y install --reinstall overlay-scrollbar-gtk2 \
                                gtk2-engines-murrine

# Install Visual Studio Code and relevant extensions
cd /
mkdir vscode && cd vscode && wget -O code_amd64 https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=760868
dpkg -i code_amd64
code --install-extension ms-vscode.cpptools --user-data-dir='/vscode/'
code --install-extension vector-of-bool.cmake-tools --user-data-dir='/vscode/'
code --install-extension ms-python.python --user-data-dir='/vscode/'
rm code_amd64
```

After building the container I shell into it using the `--nv` flag. However, doing `code . -s` does not show Visual Studio Code GUI and shows a bunch of errors such as `Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "unity-gtk-module"`, `bus.cc(427)] Failed to connect to the bus: Failed to connect to socket /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket: No such file or directory` and `dconf-CRITICAL **: unable to create directory '/run/user/1000/dconf': Permission denied. dconf will not work properly.`. Need to mention that executing `glxgears` works as expected and shows the gears running.

If I shell into my singularity container using `sudo` (which I should almost always avoid) and run `code -s --user-data-dir=''` I only get `ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(279)] Gtk: cannot open display: :0` as error and the other warnings/errors disappear. `glxgrears` also shows a similar error: `Error: couldn't open display :0` despite the fact that `echo $DISPLAY` shows `:0` when shelling into the container both **with** and **without** `sudo`.

So I wonder, how can I properly run VS Code with GUI using Docker or Singularity? Doing some search on the Internet has sort of convinced me that I am installing all the necessary modules to be able to run an application with GUI in Singularity, but why is this not happening for VS Code? Can anyone give me some clues on what's going on and/or provide a solution on how I can run the GUI when using a Singularity container.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some of the same issues and it seems that there is just a lot of "stuff" in vscode/electron that assumes that udev/dbus and access to /run/user... will be available.

I solved the issue by using a bind command; please shout if this is stupid or dangerous, but here is how I launch vscode at the moment:

```
singularity run --nv -B /run/user/$(id -u):/run/user/$(id -u) vscode.simg
```